# Is there a way to search for a common item in different objects?

Tags: java, search, methods

For instance, if I were to make a class Person, which includes name, age, and occupation, would it be possible to find all of the people who have the same age, name, etc.

I have been trying to make a monopoly game, where all of the properties have an position, and I am trying to find the property which matches the position of the player on the board. For instance if the player has travelled 5 spaces, then I would want to find a way to search for the property with the position 5, but I realized the way that I set it up would be something like:

```
public propCheck(Player player, Property property) {
  if(player.position == property.position) {
    // In here would be what would happen if the player would land on the property.
  }
}
```

which means that I would have to input the property.

Comment: Store your instances of `Property` in a `Map<Integer, Property>`. The key is the position they occupy on the board, and it allows you to obtain, for a specific position, the corresponding property.

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me what you are asking for. Can you explain better with some more code that illustrates what you want to do?

Comment: I see a way that I could complete what I am trying to do, which is try and run a method to see if they land on a property, or if they land on something else, and to see that is by using a parameter of the class Property, which is location, but I've noticed that if I were to make a method like the one I made earlier, it would require me to make a method 40 different times for every property on the board. So I was wondering if there was a way to check on every property I have made to check if in which property has the same location value as the player.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper suggested using a map to lookup the property at the player's position. As you move a player, you update its position, and then calling ```propertyMap.get(player.getPosition())``` will return the property landed upon. If you store all the details about that property -- e.g., who if anyone owns it, and what developments (hotels, houses) have been done, base rent for the property, etc. -- you can get what the player must pay for landing there. If no one owns it, the player can buy it. Or if the player is the owner, transactions can occur (buy house/hotel, sell).